# how to manage multiple loggers in python flask-tornado application

Tags: python, logging, flask, tornado

I'm building a python application with also a web interface, with Flask web framework.
It runs on Flask internal server in debug/dev mode and in production mode it runs on tornado as wsgi container.
This is how i've set up my logger:

```
log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')

file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILE, maxBytes=5 * 1024 * 1024, backupCount=10)
file_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
console_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)

log = logging.getLogger('myAppLogger')
log.addHandler(file_handler)
log.addHandler(console_handler)
```

To add my logger to the Flask app i tried this:

```
app = Flask('system.web.server')
app.logger_name = 'myAppLogger'
```

But the log still going to the Flask default log handler, and in addition, I didn't found how to customize the log handlers also for the Tornado web server.
Any help is much appreciated, 
thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to run Flask in `tornado.WSGIContainer`? Your app will only run one a single thread, thereby performing very poorly. Read the [warning](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer) in the docs. I still don't get why exactly does this functionality in Tornado even exists.

Comment: Because it's an all-in-one management app, and it's target is not high traffic,  the app will run some internal daemons plus an web interface. In-fact is not a full web application. If you have better solution for running standalone app i'm glad to listen that. Also, the main question is about logging, that is driving me crazy. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't change the default logger in Flask. You can, however, add your handlers to the default logger:

```
app = Flask('system.web.server')
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
app.logger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

---

Regarding my comment above - *"Why would you want to run Flask in tornado ..."*, ignore that. If you are not seeing any performance hit, then clearly there's no need to change your setup.

If, however, in future you'd like to migrate to a multithreaded container, you can look into `uwsgi` or `gunicorn`.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it, multiple handler, each doing their thing, so that ERROR log will not show on the INFO log as well and end up with duplicate info grrr:

*app.py*

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set format that both loggers will use:
formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

# Set logger A for known errors
log_handler = RotatingFileHandler('errors.log', maxBytes=10000, backupCount=1)
log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
a = logging.getLogger('errors')
a.addHandler(log_handler)

# Set logger B for bad exceptions
exceptions_handler = RotatingFileHandler('exceptions.log', maxBytes=10000, backupCount=1)
exceptions_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
exceptions_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
b = logging.getLogger('exceptions')
b.addHandler(exceptions_handler)

...
```

*whatever_file_where_you_want_to_log.py*

```
import logging
import traceback

# Will output known error messages to 'errors.log'
logging.getLogger('errors').error("Cannot connect to database, timeout")

# Will output the full stack trace to 'exceptions.log', when trouble hits the fan
logging.getLogger('exceptions').error(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: Counter intuitive in that it does not in anyway relate to Flask's logger. But can confirm it does work.